# Change the size of a ping

Tags: networking, ping

I would like to change the default size of my ping, to be able to test the MTU on my link.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test the maximum MTU size on a link (i.e. to test for ICMP fragmentation) you can set the `ping` packet size using the `-s` option.

For example, to find the maximum MTU you can loop over increasing packet sizes until `ping` returns an error code:

```
size=1272
while ping -s $size -c1 -M do google.com >&/dev/null; do 
  ((size+=4))
done
echo "Max MTU size: $((size-4+28))"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple solution:

**ping *-s 4024* 192.168.0.3**

Where **-s** determines the size of the packet being sent

Answer (score 1):

> Here's a very simple solution:
> ping -s 4024 192.168.0.3
> Where -s determines the size of the packet being sent

The suggestions above won't work anymore on any modern Debian based linux systems due to iputils quietly breaking:

https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/320

If the ICMP echo reply gets truncated to MTU size (or anything other than what you sent in the ICMP echo request packet), ping will print nothing!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows OS, the `-l` parameter allows to change the size of the icmp packet (the default size is 32 bytes). According to [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737478%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Here's an example of a `ping` with 1450 bytes of data:

```
ping -l 1450 131.107.8.1
```